# Adding a watermark with FFMPEG via Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ffmpeg

in my Rails app I want to use ffmpeg to add a watermark to a movie while uploading.

For that I've added the stremio-ffmpeg gem.

My code looks like this:

```
options = {watermark: Rails.root.join('public/images/logo_klein.png'), watermark_filter: {position: "RT", padding_x: 10, padding_y: 10}, custom: '-strict experimental'}

tmp_path = File.join File.dirname(current_path), "tmp_file.mp4"
file = FFMPEG::Movie.new(self.file.path)
file.transcode(tmp_path, options)

File.rename tmp_path, current_path
```

But my Image is not added to the movie. wenn I call http://localhost/images/logo_klein.php it is shown in browser (image)

What could be the problem for not added into the movie? When I follow the console out transcoding is started properly. But nothing mentioned of watermarking only transcoding is mentiond

console output:

```
 INFO -- : Running transcoding...
ffmpeg -y -i /var/www/ji/public/uploads/tmp/1466030485-10470-0                                                              013-4987/2016-06-08_09.50.55.mp4   -strict experimental /var/www/ji/public/uploads/tmp/1466030485-10470-0013-4987/tmp_file.mp4
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved

I use the ffmpeg it selve by callen the console

```
system "ffmpeg -i #{self.file.path} -vf 'movie=#{watermarkimage} [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]' -strict experimental #{tmp_path}"
```

Comment: You should be *extremely* careful when doing this. Filenames can contain spaces or hazardous symbols or commands. Use the `system("ffmpeg", "-i", self.file.path, ...)` method whenever possible. Test this with a file named `Untitled 1.mpg`.

Comment: There is no need to use the movie source filter, just declare the image like any other input: `ffmpeg -i video -i image -filter_complex overlay output`. Also, `-strict experimental` is not required unless your `ffmpeg` is old.

Comment: filter complex dosn't work thats the reason why I do it like above. Got an error when I user filter complex